# Translation of "We look forward to assisting you" in spanish

Tags: traducción, definiciones, expresiones, cortesía

I'm working on translating a script for a service desk, but I'm stumped at finding an equivalent for the ending phrase "we look forward to assisting you" in spanish. What would you advise to be a good translation that sounds natural?

Comment: Welcome to our site. We're a little strict on our translation requests, so that we don't turn into a translation service. We are happy to *help* you translate sentences, in the spirit of helping you learn the Spanish language, but we require that all translations requests show at least an attempt to translate the phrase into Spanish first. What have you come up with that we can help you clarify?

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I disagree. The issue was not of having tried to translate the grammar, for example, but that I was missing an expression that sounded natural in Spanish, for which I would have no attempts to present. If you feel this is not permitted on this board, I cannot prevent you from closing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An acceptable translation could be something like:

> "Estamos a su disposición" (more natural)

or

> "Estamos para asistirle" (a bit more strict)

Although a more strict translation would be something like:

> "Miramos para asistirle"

This is not a usual phrase in Spanish, you could translate it to something like:

> "Miramos por su satisfacción"

But it sound a bit weird on this subject. The use of "mirar por" could be translated in Spanish to "to take care of" so you could do a somewhat more or less accurate translation without losing much sense.

Other phrases IMHO better suited for ending a service desk in Spanish could be:

> "Estamos a su disposición para cualquier cosa que necesite" (At your service for anything)
>
> "No dude en contactar con nosotros para cualquier cosa que necesite" (Don't hesitate on contacting us if you need anything)

I hope this helps

Comment: "miramos por" sounds really weird to me, but "Estamos a su disposición" and "No dude en contactarnos..." sound natural and excellent.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, an alternate way of phrasing the same idea that I was missing. I went with "Estamos a su disposición", many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In **Chile** the natural expressions are:

> Estamos para servirle.
>
> Estamos a su servicio.

And also the first Bardo's suggestion:

> Estamos a su disposición